# Display contents of arraylist in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I want to show the contents of `arraylist` in an `.aspx` page.

I tried...

```
public string jl;
public ArrayList jline = new ArrayList();
public string jli { get { return jline.ToString(); } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductClick();
}

public void ProductClick()
{
    string list_name;
    string list_clicks;
    try
    {
        cn.con.Open();
        cn.cmd.Connection = cn.con;
        cn.cmd.CommandText = "Select * From user_product Inner Join latest_upload On latest_upload.ProductGUID = user_product.ProductGUID where user_product.UserGUID='" + Session["LogedUserGUID"] + "' AND Approve='" + 1 + "' ";
        dr = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            list_name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            list_clicks = dr["Count"].ToString();

            jl = "{ y: '" + list_name + "', a: '" + list_clicks + "' },";
            jline.Add(jl.ToString());

        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.con.Close();
    }
}
```

Now displaying the contents in `.aspx` page ...

```
<%= jli %>
```

I just want to show the contents of the arraylist, but it is showing `System.Collections.Arraylist` except the content.

What should I do ?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `ArrayList` when you can use [`List<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Are you using .NET 1?

Comment: It is because you are simply doing `return jline.ToString();`. This simply prints the ToString value of the ArrayList which is the just the Type name at the moment. To correctly return the string values within the ArrayList you'll have to generate a string using all the values stored. Any sort of loop and a `StringBuilder` will help to generate the contents of the ArrayList into a use-able string.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse you convert to string your whole array, you have to convert your array one by one.
Try this in your .aspx page:

```
<%
foreach(var item in jline)
{
    Response.Write(item);
}
%>
```

Comment: Why not `<%= item %>` instead?

Comment: In my mentioned way you add some c# code to your .cshtml page, while you want to add c# code to your .cshtml you have to add your c# code between <% and %> , in some cases where you want just write a c# var in .cshtml file you can write sth like <%= yourVar %> but when you want to process to your var  or list like your question you have to write your list childs like I answered.

Comment: I'm not the one that asked the question. I'm trying to get you to explain why you chose `Response.Write` instead of `<%= item %>` syntax. And by the way, there is no CSHTML. This is Web Forms, not Razor.

Comment: excuse me @mason I thought OP ask question in first comment